# how to import a function in react class component to using it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

for example i want to add a **function** to return or do something like this:

```
export const useExample = (name) => {
  const script = "hi" + " " + name;
  return script
};
```

and i want to use it in **class component** so should be this:

```
import React from 'React'
import {useExample} from "components/utils/useExample"

class App extends React.Component {

componentDidMount(){
  const hiMsg = useExample('John')
  console.log(hiMsg)
}
render(){
  return(
  <>
   <div>THIS IS AN EXAMPLE</div>
  </>
   )
}
}
```

This will give an **error** like this:
[image: React Hook "useExample" cannot be called in a class component. ...]

I know that we cannot use hooks in class components, so what is the **fix **of this **issue** to make the use Example **works?**

I just want to know how I can import external files like functions who accept parameters and do something with it, and to use this file multiple times in React class component

Comment: Does `useExample` call any hooks (eg, `useState`, `useEffect`)? If it doesn't, then simply change the name so that it doesn't start with `use`, so the lint rule won't think it's a custom hook.

Comment: As the error already states, you are not supposed to use a hook in a class component. Hooks are for functional components.
If you don't need to work with a hook in the first place, you can rename the method so it does not start with `use`. If you do need to work with a hook, you could create a HOC component that passes the hooks return value to the class component as a prop

Comment: You cannot use hooks in class components. The name of the function `use...` implies that's what it is. Change the name if it's not a hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't have `use` at the beginning of your function name, so it doesn't think it's a hook function.

Something like `getGreeting` instead of `useExample`.

Answer (score 0):

You can export only functions declared with the keyword `function` that way. If you use `const` export the functions at the bottom of your file like this:

```
export {useExample}
```

or if you have more methods in the same file, than:

```
export {useExample, someMoreFunctions}
```

Comment: Whilst this is correct, this doesn't address the main issue of the question

Comment: can you give me an example about this? (function keyword)

Comment: @underthewater - `export function getGreeting() { ... }`